# Where to securely store php scripts on a web server?

Tags: php, linux, apache

I'm creating an iOS application that when you click a button, it executes a script on my Apache web server and returns the data associated. I currently have these scripts inside /var/www/html/ but if you manually type in the address of said script in a url, it returns the data. How do I restrict this data to only my application?

I was debating storing a password in my source code and have that authenticate with my server, but I was wondering if there's a better option.

Comment: How secure does this need to be? You could just have some key that has to be verified before the request is processed. Don't use a password though, I'd suggest using a [JWT](https://jwt.io/), or just hash some jibberish with sha256/sha512